# Установить имя листа Excel текущею дату

Tags: delphi

Почему такой подход не работает. Мне нужно лист переименовать на текущею дату

Делаю примерно так

```
var dt: TDateTime
try
  ExcelApp := GetActiveOleObject('Excel.Application');
except
try
  ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
except
  ShowMessage('Cannot start Excel/Excel not installed ?');
  Exit;
end;
end;
  ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open('c:\YourFileName.xls');
  dt := Date(); //Тут дата корректная
  ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Name := DateToStr(dt); //Тут лист переименуется на не корректную дату 31.12.1899
```

Comment: Что такое `TDteTime`? В Delphi нет такого встроенного типа

Comment: У меня ошибка не фиксируется, код рабочий. Надеюсь, речь идёт о TDateTime.... Допускаю, дело в региональных настройках, как указал @ГерманБорисов

Comment: Исправьте опечатку в типе: TDteTime->TDateTime

Comment: @Азат, используйте функцию `FormatDateTime()`

Comment: @dresqd Исправил

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, Это просто моя опечатка.

Answer (score 0):

После преобразования TDateTime в строку, появляются разделители «/» (прим. 28/07/2023)
Символ «/» недопустим в названии листа.

[Ссылка на официальную страницу Microsoft, в которой описаны правила именования листов](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9)

После преобразования даты в строку попробуйте заменить «/» на «_», после чего получится переименовать лист полученной строкой (прим. 28_07_2023).

Попробуйте следующий код.

```
var 
  dt : TDateTime;
  ExcelApp, WB, WS : Variant;
  editedDT : string;
try
  ExcelApp := GetActiveOleObject('Excel.Application');
except
  try
    ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  except
    ShowMessage('Cannot start Excel/Excel not installed ?');
    Exit; 
  end;
end;
  WB := ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open('c:\YourFileName.xls');
  WS := WB.ActiveSheet;
  dt := Date(); //Тут дата корректная
  editedDT := StringReplace(dt, '/', '_', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  WS.Name := DateToStr(editedDT);
```

Comment: Дата в delphi хранится как число, у неё нет никакого "формата". Формат возникает при преобразовании в строку, и зависит от региональных настроек ОС.

Comment: Исправил формулировку ответа

Comment: @dresqd, в том то и проблема. Если вывести значение DateToStr(dt) в консоль или на messageBox то там значения верное. То есть отображается 25.01.2024. Без каких либо других символов

Comment: @Азат, отредактировал ответ, проверьте код.

Comment: [Свойство Application.ActiveSheet (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet) не должно смущать

Comment: @dresqd, Проверил данный код. Работает аналогично моему. При установки простой строчной переменной, например var Name := 'Лист 1' проблем не возникает. Именно проблема с конвертацией даты в строку. Хотя формат верный

Comment: @Азат Как выглядит?
ShowMessage('myDate = '+DateToStr(dt));

Comment: @Азат, еще раз исправил код. Последняя надежда в замене элементов строки, попробуйте.

Comment: @dresqd, ShowMessage выводит дату с точками. Так же StringReplace принимает в качестве первого аргумента строку, то есть нужно сделать DateToStr(dt). И в Вашем коде editedDT имеет значение строки, а Вы его конвертируете из даты в строку. Ну да ладно, в любом случае выдает ошибку, что в строке есть запрещенные символы. Видимо временно придется отказаться от переименование строки